# LazyInitializationException in static method

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

How does JPA session behave in static method? I'm retrieving list of objects from database using Hibernate and then transform it using Guava's static `Lists.transform` method, which causes:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session

while retrieving lazy initialized properties, even though all operations are done in one transaction. Does JPA session exist in static methods?

Here is the example:

```
@Stateless
public class OrderDaoBean {

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu")
        private EntityManager em;

        public List<OrderDTO> getAllOrders() {
            List<Order> ordersList = em.createNamedQuery("Orders", Order.class).getResultList();
            return Lists.transform(ordersList, new Function<Order, OrderDTO>() {
                @Override
                public OrderDTO apply(Order order) {
                    return new OrderDTO(order.getId(), order.getItems().size());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you having the same problem with other lazily accessed properties ? Could you show your applicationContext.xml ?

Comment: Are you sure transaction is getting created? I am not sure about EJB, but in SPring, transactions are not started in static methods IMHO

Comment: @LMeyer yes, I had this problem with many entities and many properties. I don't have applicationContext.xml :) Hirak yes, transaction is created - when I transform manually or as JB Nizet said, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with static methods. The problem is that the list returned by `Lists.transform()` is not a new list containing DTOs. It's [a *view* on the original list](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29), which transforms the elements lazily, on demand.

So the transformation function is actually called after the transaction has ended, when you start getting elements out of this list.

You should simply create a copy of the transformed list:

```
return Lists.newArrayList(Lists.tranform(...));
```